# const struct with pointer, discarded qualifier without warning

Tags: c, gcc, warnings

I have a structure with a pointer to something. I was expecting that accessing this pointer via a pointer-to-const-struct to the struct gives me a pointer-to-const-something. But gcc does not produce a warning in this case:

```
#include <stdlib.h>    
    
struct S {    
    void* ptr;    
};    
    
struct S* create(void)    
{    
    struct S* S = malloc(sizeof(*S));    
    S->ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));    
    return S;    
}    
    
void some_func(void* p);    
    
int main(void)    
{    
    struct S* S = create();    
    const void* ptr = S->ptr;    
    const struct S* SC = S;    
    some_func(ptr); // warning as expected    
    some_func(SC->ptr); // no warning    
}
```

So is `SC->ptr` actually a `const void*`? I always assumed but now I'm confused. Is there a possibility to get a warning in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SC->ptr` is a `void * const`. It is not a `const void *` or `const void * const`.

`const struct S* SC = S;` defines `SC` to be a pointer to a `struct S` that is `const`-qualified. The fact the structure is `const`-qualified means you should not modify the structure. The structure contains a member `ptr` of type `void *`. Because the structure is `const`-qualified, its members are `const`-qualified. That means you should not change `ptr`. Its type is `void * const`.

However, that does not affect what `ptr` points to. Regardless of whether `ptr` itself is `const`-qualified, it points to `void`, not to `const void`.

The C standard does not provide good means of working with multiple versions of a structure in which one version has members that point to non-`const` types and the other has members that point to `const` types. In general, there is no good way to convert one such structure into the other type.

Comment: Thanks, never thought of it like that, this reasoning makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

> So is SC->ptr actually a `const void*`?

No.  `SC->ptr` is an expression designating an object of type `void *`, which expression you may not use to modify the value of that object.  (There might, in principle, be other expressions designating the same object by which it *could* be modified.) This is similar to, but not exactly the same as, a `void * const` -- *the pointer* cannot be modified.  There is no implication on modifying the data to which it points.

> ```
>     some_func(SC->ptr); // no warning
> ```

[...]

> Is there a possibility to get a warning in this case?

C semantics provide no particular reason to diagnose anything suspicious or wrong about that case, because again, it is the pointer that must not be modified, not the data to which it points.  And because the pointer is passed by value, there is no way for the function to modify it.